# How to read and write csv files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I'm trying to learn how to read and write python, but it's really confusing me and I can't seem to find anywhere that tells me what I want to know.

I'm currently working on a Collatz conjecture problem:

```
list=[]

def collatz(a):
    if a%2==0:
        return a/2
    else:
        return (3*a)+1

    number = input("Please enter range: ")+1
    print "\n\n"
    for x in range(1,number):
        n=x
        count=(-1)
        while n>=1:
            print "%s " % (n),
            if n<x:
                count += list[n-1]
                n=0
            if n==1:
                n=0
            n=collatz(n)
            count+=1
        print "\n\n%s: %s\n\n" % (x, count)
        f.write("%s %s\n" % (x, count))
        list.insert(x,count)
        x+=1
```

I just want to output the data so that I can graph it in excel, but also so that I can save the data there (instead of the list) to refer to later (so, say I run it to 100,000, the next time I enter it, I want it to start from 100,001 and access the data from the file in the same way as I do with the list above).

I'm trying to learn how to do it myself, but for some reason I just keep getting confused.

With regards to formatting, I would like to save the starting number on the first column and then save the number in the second column.

Comment: Use pandas or numpy.

Comment: You can consider csv as a comma separated text file. It means that just using methods like open() and readlines() are fine.

Comment: Please create [mcve].

Comment: Many folks read and write csv files with the built-in `csv` module. See the examples in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv). You should also read (and follow) the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which includes **not** naming your own variables the same as built-in functions and types (like `list`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library (or [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for python 3) to work with csv data. It has methods for reading and writing csv files, and these will work much better than anything you write for yourself.

In this case, I would suggest using [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) instead ([python3 link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)). This is a tool which allows you to access a flat file as if it were a database, which will probably save you a lot of trouble.